Firebase crash at peak
I am currently developping an app about tickets for my school. I am developping it on FlutterFlow, so I am using Firebase.
Thus, I have a question. I will have maximum 50 people connected at the same time in normal time. But, when few important event will release, I will get between 1000 and 1500 that will try to connect and buy tickets in seconds.
Another app was used for the tickets by my school and it was crashing when events was releasing. They were using aws or firebase (not sure). And I do not know why they had this problem.
I want to avoid this, because after the first crash their app has been excluded by my school. Do you know if I will have the same problem with firebase blaze plan ?
In the FAQ it is written that I will have up to 200,000 simultaneous connections, but the problem is that I will go from 50 users to probably 1500 people trying to buy a ticket just in minutes or less. Can Firestore easily scales up ?
Or is it possible to send a "preventive message" using scripts to Firestore to scale up before the event releases ?

Firebase is highly scaleable and 1000 users is really nothing in terms of what Firebase can handle. Handling errors or conflicts is solely up to the developer but again, Firebase can handle the workload. It's not clear what - preventive message - you want to send but it could be totally unnecessary. I suggest writing some code!

Oh ok  I was asking like making the server go bigger by sending a request with a script. As I have the tickets date I was thinking that I could prevent the server from a peak. But if it’s ok with a peak of 1000 users it should be ok. I am wondering why the other app was crashing


Can Firestore easily scales up ?

Yes.

Or is it possible to send a "preventive message" using scripts to Firestore to scale up before the event releases ?

No.
I think you are overly concerned about scaling.  You tagged this question with Firestore, so you should get familiar with the documented limits of the product, and do whatever planning you must do to make sure the limits aren't going to be exceeded.  We can't do that for you.  Or, if you feel that limits might be exceeded, you need to do proper error handling.
If you are worried about crashes, that is entirely your responsibility in your code to capture any errors that happen and deal with them gracefully.  Firebase can't do that for you.  Firebase services won't spontaneously crash under load, but errors can and will happen, and that's always your responsibility to cover.

Thank you for your comment! I am not exceeding the limits. It should work then. I will be careful about eventual crashes. Is there a way to simulate 1000 users that try to connect and test the app at the same time? I know how to do it on website server but not on mobile apps..

A client connection has the same effect no matter where it comes from or how it connects. A connection on its own also doesn't do anything.  The client app making the connection needs to make queries in order to apply load that would cause limits to be reached.
